# Autocompletion from include files for .tex files

Tags: vim, autocomplete, latex

At present, I use VIM as my `.tex` editor. The only include file I need are from included bibliography files. These bibliography files are sourced from within the `.tex` file so:

```
\bibliography{../CentralRepository.bib}
```

This essentially sources content from the file `CentralRepository.bib` which resides separately in the parent folder of the current `.tex` folder I am editing. All other completions I need for `.tex` editing come from a snippets engine that I manage separately.

How can I specify that the include autocompletion triggered by `<C-X><C-i>` need only look at the `.bib` file sourced above?

At present, the output of `:set include?` is the following:

```
include=\v^\c\s*\%\s*!?\s*tex\s+root\s*\=\s*\zs.*\ze\s*$|\v^\s*\zs%(\v\\%(input|include)\s*\{|\v\\%(subfile%(include)?|%(sub)?%(import|%(input|include)from)\*?\{[^\}]*\})\s*\{)\zs[^\}]*\ze\}?|\v\\%(usepackage|RequirePackage)%(\s*\[[^]]*\])?\s*\{\zs[^}]*\ze\}
```

Reading through `:h include`, the above seems to be a search pattern to identify files to include. I do not want all of the above. My requirements are only that the `CentralRepository.bib` file be considered for `<C-X><C-i>` type autocompletion.

How can this be specified?

As of now, whenever I press `<C-X><C-i>` I am able to see at the bottom of the screen:

`scanning included file: .....`

VIM is trying to search through a huge number of included files in various directories for completion suggestions. This is an overkill and unnecessary for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `:help 'include'` is a regular expression pattern used by Vim to find includes in the buffer. It doesn't *have* to be ultra precise so you could get away with a simple:

```
" in after/ftplugin/plaintex.vim
setlocal include=bibliography
```

which you can check with:

```
:checkpath!
--- Included files in path ---
../CentralRepository.bib
```

But, `bibliography` is a relatively common English word so you might want to make your pattern more specific. Something like:

```
setlocal include=^\\s*\\\\bibliography{
```

Comment: This works fine. Except that `:echo &filetype` returns `tex` and not `plaintex` from within VIM when a `.tex` file is loaded. So, I had a `tex.vim` in the folder you suggested and it works fine.